# Chrome Extension Authentication session

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that requires extension. Where's the best place to store this session data in the extension?

I know chrome has their own API for cookies/session, but didn't know if there was some best practices around this.

Thanks!

Comment: it's depend your need. Do you want to save it just for session or for long time ? can you give more details please.

Comment: Yeah sure...it's authentication data. Really saving an API key, so i'd like it to be long lived just to not burden them with re-logging in.

Comment: Would I just use localstorage from within the extension to save this stuff?

Comment: In my opinion the best way is to use the chrome storage API. It can be local or synchronize with account. The data is saved until the ext is uninstall.